# React: Material UI, Total Rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What is the maximum number of rows that are supported by Material UI in REACT in free or paid versions

I have a huge dataset more than 400 MB of data. Is this too crazy or achievable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Material-UI data grid renders only 101 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68370373/material-ui-data-grid-renders-only-101-rows)
I have used datagrid with more than 650,000 records and it works fine with a bit of lag. But, you need to pay for premium to use display more than 100 rows per page.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely achievable.

MUI Data Grid can support as much data as it gets, and you can manually define the amount of rows per page you want to show at a time. I suggest you don't go over the suggested default limit of 100 to avoid lag.

Also, bear in my mind, you should use pagination in your backend service for this, otherwise the request will take quite some time to load the data :)